# C++: Default Arguments and Vectors

Tags: c++, function, vector, optional-parameters

In C++, I want to have a function that takes an optional argument of type vector. If the argument is not provided, I want the variable to have size 0. I currently have

```
void v_connect::import(vector<int> vid_,vector<double> vpos_,vector<int> vbd_,vector<int>    bd_ss_=std::vector<int>() )
```

But this doesn't work. Basically, if the user provides the optional argument `bd_ss_` I want to do a check `bd_ss_.size()!=0` and then do some extra stuff. If the user does not provide the argument, I want `bd_ss.size()==0`. Is this possible?

Comment: Wow you're really taking a copy of all of those vectors?! `const vector<int> &vid_, ...`

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to tell whether or not an optional argument is user-provided. However, you could use an overload:

```
void v_connect::import(
    std::vector<int> vid_,
    std::vector<double> vpos_,
    std::vector<int> vbd_,
    std::vector<int> bd_ss_) 
{
    check(!bd_ss_.empty());
    do_extra_stuff();
    do_import(vid_, cpos_, vbd_, bd_ss_);
}

void v_connect::import(
    std::vector<int> vid_,
    std::vector<double> vpos_,
    std::vector<int> vbd_) 
{
    do_import(vid_, cpos_, vbd_, std::vector<int>());
}

// private:
void v_connect::do_import(
    std::vector<int> vid_,
    std::vector<double> vpos_,
    std::vector<int> vbd_,
    std::vector<int> bd_ss_)
{
    // common import code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make the user pass a pointer instead:

```
void foo(std::vector<int> * ov = NULL)
{
    std::vector<int> dummy;
    std::vector<int> & bd_ss_ = ov ? *ov : dummy;

    if (ov) assert(!bd_ss_.empty());

    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, use [Boost.optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), which is a clever C++-style wrapper around this idea and allows you to have the same behaviour with a seamless interface.

Answer (score 2):

Optional parameters go in the header, not the cpp.

As an aside you're mixing vector and std::vector, use one or the other (prefer to stick to std::vector).

Comment: Not 100% true, each argument can be defaulted in the header or the implementation (more precisely: declaration or definition) as long as when an argument is defaulted, all later arguments in the signature are defaulted (or have been previously defaulted). +1 anyway, as this is most probably the cause of the issue.